# How to run using python3.7 from brew install?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

Sorry if this is too basic, but if you could point me in the right direction I will be grateful.

I am using a macbook m1 machine and I'm a newbie at using macs. I'm trying to install python3.7 from this guide: https://diewland.medium.com/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-macbook-m1-87c5b0fcb3b5.

I think I was able to install python3.7 using ibrew with no issues. But when I run **python3 --version**, it still shows python3.8.

I also tried running **whereis python3.7** and it is not able to find any results for some reason.

Are there other steps for me to run python3.7 which I installed via ibrew?

Answer (score 0):

it is actually in /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7